# Server fails on reboot after updates

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage, sas

Okay - this is an HP ML340 G9 one year out of warranty.

Last weekend I decided to allow Windows (2012 Essentials)
to update. On restart, server dead/no boot.

Storage manager says no drives (there are 6 1TB SAS).
I replaced the Array card even though is shows healthy
and its LEDs say normal, idle.

The last 4 drives show amber, the 1st 2 are dark.
when I pull out the last 4, the storage manager finds
the first 2, says not configured. When I plug the last
4 back in, "no configurable drives found"

Anyone ever run into this before? Is it possible to
lose 4 drives all at once? Has my beautiful server
battleship turned into a boat anchor?

All opinions welcome at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Having backup I hope? How much uptime before the reboot ? could be a storage issue resolved by a firmware in example

Comment: I did have good backups. I was able to get my users up and running with a borrowed server.  The  system was up for

Comment: several months before this reboot. Firmware updates? Worth a try.

Comment: I would try it incase it’s a backplane failure. What raid level the 6 disks was on ?

Comment: 2 drives Raid 1, 4 drives Raid 5

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna answer it with basic solutions, you can pass if you don't like my suggestions; I had a similar issue with hostnoc, and I resolved it with these solutions;

- If your Disks/Server is in warranty claim it.
- Try to switch to other power cords.
- If it is related to update then try to restore it to the initial version.